# Extending a block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, extend, dependency-injection, factory

I'm trying to extend `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` to add some functionalities. I have let PHPStorm generate the constructor method for me and that worked fine.

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    array $data
){
    parent::__construct($context, $urlEncoder, $jsonEncoder, $string, $productHelper, $productTypeConfig, $localeFormat, $customerSession, $productRepository, $priceCurrency, $data);
}
```

But as soon as I add a custom class factory to the constructor it breaks and I get 404 page when I try to visit the product view page.
I used the same factory in Adminhtml blocks and observers, so I figured this should work the same way.

```
protected $_awesomeModelFactory;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    array $data,
    \MyAwesome\Mobule\Model\AwesomeModelFactory $awesomeModelFactory
){
    $this->_awesomeModelFactory = $awesomeModelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $urlEncoder, $jsonEncoder, $string, $productHelper, $productTypeConfig, $localeFormat, $customerSession, $productRepository, $priceCurrency, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the order of arguments given to your custom block.

`$data` should always come last.

On top of that, you forgot to specify a class for the `$productRepository` parameter in the constructor.

Thus you need to update your constructor with the following code:

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \MyAwesome\Mobule\Model\AwesomeModelFactory $awesomeModelFactory,
    array $data = []
){
    $this->_awesomeModelFactory = $awesomeModelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $urlEncoder, $jsonEncoder, $string, $productHelper, $productTypeConfig, $localeFormat, $customerSession, $productRepository, $priceCurrency, $data);
}
```

Natively in Magento, the `Magento\Review\Block\Product\View` is a good working example on how to extend the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` if you want to have a look at this class.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. Of course you are right about the order of the arguments in the constructor. That didn't solve it for me. Turns out I have been wasting my time for the past hour..... I just had to run php bin/magento setup:di:compile again. I keep forgetting all the new CLI options and that only cleaning the cache won't do the trick.